# Color a Text on the python shell

Tags: python, text, colors

I've made several attempts.

The first code I've tried is this one:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

print(Fore.RED + 'This text is red in color')
```

but the output is not what I was expecting

[image]

then I've tried this:

```
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint
text = colored('Hello, World!', 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])
print(text)
```

but again the result is not correct

[image]

is there a kind of a setting to setup in order to see the colored text or is it just  a problem of python version?
The version I'm using as shell is 3.10.4

Comment: I think you should use `blessings` module, because it is one of the few modules which understand terminals (colorama will just assume some terminal capability, blessings will ask terminal and uses only capabilities which terminal supports, so no ugly text on redirect or on dump terminals). In any case, from output, it seems that your terminal doesn't understand CSI (escape sequences). So the problem is on your terminal.

Comment: I'm using the Idle Shell 3.10.4 that cames frome python installation.  I agree that the problem is on the shell I'm using. Do you have a link/reference to this module? I'm quite new in python programming. Thanks

Comment: The module is: https://github.com/erikrose/blessings , but it will not solve your problem, it will just understand that your shell is not accepting colours

Comment: It seems idle shell do not support normal colours. There is a trick, e.g. https://github.com/lawsie/idlecolors or the original question: https://github.com/lawsie/idlecolors but it is an hack and it works only on IDLE. In short: do not use IDLE for colour shell. And I think IDLE was not more recommended. Use spyder https://www.spyder-ide.org/ or many other free python user IDEs

Comment: Grazie Giacomo!thanks for your help. the last comment helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The code is working perfectly:

[image]

Try restarting the text editor or something.

Comment: no I've done this attempt as well, rebooting the pc....nothing...it doesn't work

Comment: If you answer, put the relevant text into the answer (not just link). And I think your answer is not an answer but a comment

Comment: The code is exactly the same, so what else was I suppose to answer with other than a screenshot that shows that the code works.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know colorama and termcolor but I can suggest what I did in the past for colored text

```
def display_blue(msg):
    print('\033[94m'+msg+'\033[0m')

def display_red(msg):
    print('\033[91m'+msg+'\033[0m')

def display_green(msg):
    print('\033[92m'+msg+'\033[0m')

def display_yellow(msg):
    print('\033[93m'+msg+'\033[0m')
```

Comment: no... same results of the immage I've uploaded in the main question

Comment: Can you run the code from cmd and share the results?

Answer (score -1):

I hope it would be helpful

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
print(f"{Fore.RED}This is Red Color")
```

Comment: same as the previous 3 reply.... I think the issue is related to IDLE shell which is not "traslating" the color

Answer (score -1):

As suggested elsewhere, the problem may be that your terminal window doesn't support colours. And so the IDLE Shell simply prints the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), e.g. `\033[31m`.

Note that it's best practice to always reset the terminal colour/style when using inline ANSI escape codes. Otherwise, the colour/style will spill over into subsequent messages in the terminal. So your example...

```py
from colorama import Fore

print(Fore.RED + 'This text is red in color')
```

... should look more like this:

```py
from colorama import Fore

print(Fore.RED + 'This text is red in color' + Fore.RESET)
```

Another method could be to use other, simpler Python packages. For example [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) (which I'm the author of, in full disclosure). Just write:

```py
from colorist import red

red("This text is red in color")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also apply the colour/style using f-strings or regular string appends with [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/):

```py
from colorist import Color

print(f"{Color.RED}This text is red in color{Color.OFF}")

print(Color.RED + "This text is red in color" + Color.OFF)
```

Or even more lightweight, create your own class:

```py
class Color():
  RED = "\033[31m"
  OFF = "\033[0m"

print(Color.RED + "This text is red in color" + Color.OFF)
```

Comment: Ciao, I've tried the commands you've written and noone worked. In particular the last two with colorist and enum give me this error "  print(Color.RED + "This text is red in color" + Color.OFF)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Color' and 'str'"

Comment: @martinmistere: Which version of Python are you running? For instance and as you may know, earlier versions of Python don't support f-strings, enum, etc.

Comment: @martinmistere: I just updated the code above and released a new version of Colorist that supports both string concatenation and f-strings. If you don't mind, please try again.

Comment: python idle shell 3.11.0

Comment: I recommend using another terminal window now that, as far as I know, the Python IDLE shell doesn't support ANSI colour codes. Would that work for you?

Comment: which one do you suggest?

Comment: Assuming that you're on a Windows machine, I imagine that the standard terminal should work fine. (I mostly use Mac so I'm not an expert here.) If you use Mac, the standard terminal app works fine. I hope it helps.